# Is there easy way to include xlnt to Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, xlsx

I want to use xlnt library to edit xlsx data but i don't know how to input this to global libraries of VSC. Could you please tell me step by step how install this library?

https://github.com/tfussell/xlnt

Answer (score 1):

You need some packages firstly:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install cmake
sudo apt-get install zlibc
```

The following steps update the compiler and set the appropriate environment variables:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install gcc-6 g++-6
export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-6  
export CXX=/usr/bin/g++-6
```

The following steps will intall xlnt Download the zip file from the xlnt repository:

```
cd ~
unzip Downloads/xlnt-master.zip
cd xlnt-master
cmake .
make -j 2
sudo make install
```

The following step will map the shared library names to the location of the corresponding shared library files:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

xlnt will now be ready to use on your Ubuntu instance.

[source](https://tfussell.gitbooks.io/xlnt/content/docs/introduction/Installation.html)

Comment: Can you add the main points from the link to the answer itself? That's required by the rules in case the link dies one day.

Comment: It doesn't work. I have still communicats: undefined references. Is this problem with linker?

Comment: maybe try the "Compiling from Source" rubric from the link